# Toggle visibility of only one of a group of layers?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

I have 5 layers in a group in Photoshop that represent five states of an app screen. Only one would be shown at a time. Is there a way to get Photoshop so that it only solo's one of the five in the group, but leave unchanged other layers outside the group? In other words, if I try to solo one of them, any other ones currently visible go invisible, but other layers outside the group remain visible.

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

You can option-click a layer's visibility icon in the layers panel to solo it, but I don't believe that can be done while keeping layers in another group enabled. I usually structure things so that each app state is a group itself. It can mean there's some duplication, but makes viewing an entire state easy.

You could use Layer Comps, but I find them more trouble than they're worth, for documents that are still being actively worked on (and therefore having layers added and removed).